# Permission denied when connecting from public EC2 instance to private EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I see there are multiple solutions to fix this by modifying the config file.

But I don't understand how to modify the config file of the private EC2 machine without logging in as I am getting this error while logging into the linux machine.

I could never login to the private instance. I have added EC2 full access role to my public EC2 and keypairs for both the instances are same. I saw many videos that after all these setups we can directly ssh to private EC2 from public EC2. I could login to public ec2 using .pem stored in my local and after that I tried `ssh privateIPofprivateEC2` and ended up with this error.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details. For example: Have you ever been able to connect to the instance? If so, what has changed? The error says that you are using the wrong keypair, so what makes you think that you have the correct keypair?

Comment: i could never login to the private instance .I have added EC2 full access role to my public EC2 and keyparis for both the instances are same .I saw many vedios that after all these setups we can directly ssh to private EC2 from public EC2 .               I could login to public ec2 using .pem stored in my local and after that i tried "ssh privateIPofprivateEC2" and ended up with this error .

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- You have successfully used ssh to connect to a "public" Amazon EC2 instance
- You are now wanting to use ssh to connect from there to a "private" Amazon EC2 instance
- When you use `ssh privateIPofprivateEC2`, you are receiving a **Permission Denied** error

The error is indicating that you have not successfully authenticated to the private instance. This is because you **did not provide a private keypair** in the ssh command (like was done when connecting to the public instance).

Assuming that the private instance has been launched with the same keypair as the public instance, you can connect to the private instance by using **agent forwarding**.

On your own computer:

```
ssh-add key.pem
ssh -A ec2-user@PUBLIC-INSTANCE-IP-ADDRESS
```

On the public instance:

```
ssh PRIVATE-IP-ADDRESS
```

See: [Using SSH Agent Forwarding | GitHub Developer Guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/)